# ERROR: (bq) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

My scripts to load the data from Compute Engine to BigQuery failed, it's running well every day, but for the first time I received this error:

```
ERROR: (bq) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/numbers-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com/token from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Response:
{'status': '504', 'content-length': '18', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'metadata-flavor': 'Google', 'server': 'Metadata Server for VM', 'connection': 'Close', 'date': 'Wed, 08 Apr 2020 14:32:07 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
        Please run:

          $ gcloud auth login

        to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
        different account:

          $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

        to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

Then I run the same script again without doing any changes, and it is working again. What happened?

Comment: Are you manually authentication with the CLI `gcloud`. You should be using a Compute Engine service account.

Comment: Is the issue back? I'm getting the same error today.

Answer (score 0):

There was an internal issue with Cloud IAM that caused several GCP products to fail.

Since you mentioned that your scripts ran well before and they recently failed, I think you were affected by this as well.

The issue has been fixed already but it will take some time to be replicated over all Google's infrastructure.

For more details see [GCP infrastructure incident April 8, 2020](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/zall/20005)

Comment: I think this is the case. Does Data Studio get affected? As I received some people cannot view the dashboard at that time.

Comment: Not quite sure that Data Studio itself went down but since data is normally imported from affected services like BigQuery or from Google cloud storage, I would say that the outage of these services could have affected visualization in Data Studio at that time.